# After refreshing the page product adding automatically in cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to make the code for a shopping cart, which is working. However, when I refresh the page it's adding a product to my cart automatically.

For example, I have 3 products on my website, which are `Apple, Banana, Orange`.
I click on Apple and it's added to my cart with QTY 1 and the URL is showing

```
`mydomain.com/my-cart?action=addcart&p_id=FylvGt6Yyb6n%2BzTXcJHwjBawOY%2Fw3QSZxF7rdUJLqhA%3D#`
```

Now if I refresh the page then it's adding another `Apple` to my cart (QTY 2). Then if I refresh the page again it adds another `Apple` (QTY 3) and so on. I don't know why this is happing. It's adding to SESSION.

Would you help me in this?

Below Is my cart code.

```
    $action = isset($_GET['action'])?$_GET['action']:"";
       $p_id=$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['p_id']);
       $decrypted_p_id = decryptIt($p_id);
    //Add to cart
    if($action=='addcart') {
        //Finding the product by code
     $query = "SELECT p_unique_id, p_images,p_name, p_currentprice FROM products WHERE p_id=?";
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $decrypted_p_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($p_unique_id,$p_images, $p_name, $p_currentprice);
        $stmt->fetch();

}
        $currentQty = $_SESSION['products'][$decrypted_p_id]['qty']+1; //Incrementing the product qty in cart
        $_SESSION['products'][$decrypted_p_id] =array(
                                            'qty'=>$currentQty,
                                            'p_unique_id'=>$p_unique_id,
                                            'p_images'=>$p_images,
                                            'p_name'=>$p_name,
                                            'p_currentprice'=>$p_currentprice
                                        );
        $product='';
       // header("Location:cart.php");
    }
```

**Displaying product**

```
  <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['products'])):
   foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$product):?>
    /*some code here*/
    endforeach;?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Edited code here Suggested by ADyson

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $action=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['action']);
       $decrypted_p_id=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['p_id']);
// whole code here
```

Comment: yes because if you simply click refresh of the exact same page then action=addcart etc. is still in the URL, so it runs that action again. To be honest an "add" action like that would be better done as a POST request, partly for semantic reasons (it's "sending" data rather than "get"ting it) and partly to avoid annoyances like this. Ideally a GET request should not cause any change of state in the application.

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. Escaping the string is not safe on its own - that function was never intended to protect against injection attacks (although in some circumstances, it can, but not always and not by design).

Comment: @ADyson, now I updated my code in prepared statements. Now is it ok?

Comment: @ADyson, Can you share some example of  POST request in the shopping cart?

Comment: well I don't know how you're making that request to the URL in the first place, but if it's done via a HTML form then change its "method" attribute to "POST", and look for $_POST variables instead of $_GET in the PHP. You can find plenty of simple examples of POST requests online as well.

Comment: @ADyson, <a href="my-cart?action=addcart&p_id=<?php echo $p_user_id;?>">Add to cart</a>, I am trying like this

Comment: a hyperlink will always cause a GET, no matter what. You could make it into a little form instead, with the action and p_id as hidden fields. You'd need a button instead of a link, but you can use CSS to make a button look like a link if you need to. If you can't make it work I can do a little example.

Comment: @ADyson, Can you share the code for the sample?

Answer (score 0):

i found this code:

```
$currentQty = $_SESSION['products'][$decrypted_p_id]['qty']+1;
```

this code always run when u reload the page, 
give some condition if you want to add manually

Comment: What condition I have to use it here?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply click refresh on the exact same page then `action=addcart` etc. is still in the URL. Therefore inevitably it runs that action again when the page loads, and adds the items to the cart again.

An "add" action like that would be better done as a POST request, partly for semantic reasons (it's "sending" data rather than "get"ting it) and partly to avoid annoyances like this. Ideally a GET request should not cause any change of state in the application.

Instead of

```
<a href="my-cart?action=addcart&p_id=<?php echo $p_user_id;?>">Add to cart</a>
```

you can do something like:

```
<form action="my-cart" method="POST">
  <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addcart"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="p_id" value="<?php echo $p_user_id;?>"/>
</form>
```

You can use some CSS to make the button appear more like your old hyperlink, if you wish.

Then, in your PHP cart code, simply replace all references to `$_GET` with `$_POST` instead, to read the values from the POST request.

This will have the advantage that the variables are not saved into the URL and therefore if someone tries to refresh the URL it will not automatically repeat the same action based on those variables.

You could also look into sending the data to add cart items via AJAX, so that it doesn't require a postback at all and usually results in a smoother user experience - if you look at most shopping websites now, that is generally what they do.

Comment: I tried your code, Now this time URL is mydomain.com/mycart but If I refresh the page then I am facing the same issue, Even I change the GET to POST

Comment: I added code to my question at the end. And When I refresh the page I am getting confirm popup Resend or Cancel

Comment: yes that's the default behaviour of the web. Nothing you can do about it. But at least it's not automatically a problem any more. User is warned and can cancel it. Hopefully the user won't try to refresh it again once they see that. If that's not sufficient you can try an AJAX solution as I suggested.