# How to change the total amount according to quantity using php

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, html

I am creating a shopping cart using session which is working, Now I am making the quantity part I mean User can increase the product quantity and decrease the quantity and according to that the total amount will display on screen without refresh the page.
I just need when the user clicked on Plus sign then the amount will change as per quantity.

`<?php echo $product['qty'];?>` I am getting this value from my session

Any idea how can I do this?
I also added same code in https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/uLx0912t/

```
 /*increase the product qty*/
  $(".ddd").on("click", function () {
    var $button = $(this),
        $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input");
    var oldValue = $input.val(),
        newVal;
    if ($.trim($button.text()) == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 1) {
            newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 1;
        }
    }
    $input.val(newVal);
});
```

**Second code after suggested Mr.A. Iglesias**

```
$('a.ddd').click(function() {

    var $productContainer = $(this).closest('div.sp-quantity');
    var $pro_list = $(this).closest('tr.pro-list');
    var productPrice = parseInt($pro_list.find('span.price_cal').text());
    var $quantityInput = $productContainer.find('input.quntity-input');
    var newQuantity = parseInt($quantityInput.val()) + parseInt($(this).data('multi'));

    if (newQuantity>= 0) {

        // Refresh quantity input.
        $quantityInput.val(newQuantity);

        // Refresh total div.
        var currentChange = productPrice*parseInt($(this).data('multi'));
        var total = parseInt($('div#total').text());
        $('div#total').text(total + currentChange);
    }

});
```

**Css**

```
.sp-quantity {
    width:124px;
    height:42px;
    float: left;
}
.sp-minus {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.sp-input {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-left:0px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.sp-plus {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-left:0px solid #e1e1e1;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.sp-input input {
    width:30px;
    height:34px;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;
}
.sp-input input:focus {
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border: none;
}
.sp-minus a, .sp-plus a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

**HTMl**

```
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['products'])):
                           foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$product):?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="pro-list">
                            <td>
                                <div class="ordered-product cf">
                                    <div class="pro-img">
                                        <img src="admin/images/products/<?php echo $product['p_images'];?>" alt=" prodcut image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pro-detail-name">
                                        <h3><?php echo $product['p_name'];?></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php 
                                    $p_delete=$product['p_id'];
                                    //$decrypted_delete_id = decryptIt($p_delete);
                                    $encrypted_user_id = encryptIt($p_delete);
                                    $delete_product_id=urlencode($encrypted_user_id);
                                    ?>

                                    <a href="my-cart?action=empty&deletekey=<?php echo $delete_product_id;?>" class="cross-cta"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>&#163;<span id="price_cal"><?php echo $product['p_currentprice'];?></span></td>
                            <td>

                                <div class="sp-quantity">
                                    <div class="sp-minus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="-1">-</a></div>
                                    <div class="sp-input">
                                        <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="<?php echo $product['qty'];?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sp-plus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="1">+</a></div>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                                <?php $single_total = $product['qty']*$product['p_currentprice'];?>
                                <td class='total_amount' data-price='&#163;<?php echo $single_total;?>'>&#163;<?php echo $single_total;?></td>
                        </tr>
                            <?php $total = $total+$single_total;
                            $_SESSION['total_cost']=$total;
                            endforeach;?>
                        <tr class="pro-list">
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span>Subtotal</span></td>
                            <td>&#163;<?php $_SESSION['total_cost']=$total;echo $total;?></td>
<!--                             <td><span>Shiping Cost</span></td>
                            <td><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#163;<?php echo $total;?></td> -->
                        </tr>


                        <tr class="pro-list">
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span>Total Cost</span></td>
                            <td>&#163;<?php echo $total;?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php endif;?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

for total amount, I added this in the script.

```
  // Refresh total div.
 var subtotal_amount = subtotal_amount+lineTotal; 
  $pro_list.find('td.subtotal_amount').data('price','&#163;'+subtotal_amount).html('&#163;'+subtotal_amount);
```

HTML inside `<tr class="pro-list">`

```
<td class='subtotal_amount' data-price='&#163;<?php echo $total;?>'>&#163;<?php echo $total;?></td>
```

Comment: You assigned `$product = 10`. and then you echoed `echo $product['qty'];`. in the input of quantity

Comment: @vher2, Yes, $product = 10 is the price of the product and $product['qty']; is coming from my session which is the quantity of product.

Comment: But the `$product` has a value of `10`. is not an array anymore if you do that

Comment: @vher2, ok, That I will update it with $product1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can put your product price and the total amount inside of div with a class or id, to make them easy to select, something like...

```
<?php $product=10;?>

<div class="sp-quantity">

    <div class="product-price"><?=$product?></div>

    <div class="sp-minus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="-1">-</a></div>
    <div class="sp-input">
        <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="<?php echo $product['qty'];?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="sp-plus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="1">+</a></div>

</div>

<?php
$single_total = $product['qty']*$product;
echo $total = $total + $single_total;
?>
<div id="total"><?=$total?></div>
```

Then, refresh its values anytime you change the quantity of a product...

```
$('a.ddd').click(function() {

    var $productContainer = $(this).closest('div.sp-quantity');
    var productPrice = parseInt($productContainer.find('div.product-price').text());
    var $quantityInput = $productContainer.find('input.quntity-input');
    var newQuantity = parseInt($quantityInput.val()) + parseInt($(this).data('multi'));

    if (newQuantity>= 0) {

        // Refresh quantity input.
        $quantityInput.val(newQuantity);

        // Refresh total div.
        var currentChange = productPrice*parseInt($(this).data('multi'));
        var total = parseInt($('div#total').text());
        $('div#total').text(total + currentChange);
    }

});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: @A.lglesias, Thanks for the reply, Are you sure this will increase or decrease the total amount without refresh the page?I don't have any issue with quantity. I am getting proper if I clicked on Plus and Minus sign.

Comment: @A.lglesias, Sorry for the late reply, I tried your code, I am not able to calculate the amount if I enter the   <div class="product-price"><?=$product?></div> this div outside of parent div

Comment: Second Issue is, I select 3 qty so the total amount will be 30 now What I did I refresh the page then I got 3 qty and amount is 0.

Comment: If you put `div.product-price` outside of the `div.sp-quantity`, you just have to change the selector ($productContainer.find('div.product-price') in my example) to one that fits the new ubication. 
If you want to persist data in a refresh, you have to save it in some place. You could use LocalStorage or SessionStorage (most of current browsers have it), depending on if you want the data to persist until you delete it (or the browser decides that needs the space) or if you want the data to persist only for current session

Comment: @A.lglesias, Sorry for the late reply. I tried but getting the issue, I update HTML my cart page code, Can you help me out in this. Please

Comment: For your new html, `$button.closest('tr').find('span#price_cal')` will select you the product price span. A piece of advice, `id` is design to be unique in your DOM, for your case I think you should use a class.

Comment: You mean to say I have to replace $(this).closest('tr.pro-list'); with $button.closest('tr').find('span#price_cal').??

Comment: @A.lglesias, I update my script please check it and assist me.

Comment: First, in the javascript code your'e using `span.price_cal`, but in your html that span has an `id`, change your HTML to a class. For the line total, you are using my code without changing the selector. Here you have a working fiddle that refresh the line total (the cart total is up to you) https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/m59xyej6/

Comment: Hello, Mr.A.lglesias, I really appreciate your efforts and support. This time it's working. I just want to know that How to change the final cost on same. Now it's changing the amount but how can I change the final amount depending upon the total single product?

Comment: @A.lglesias, Please help me out in this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Your code is solved my issue. upvote from my side

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand, but the total amount corresponds to total price (depended on product's quantity), isn't it ?
If I'm right, I think the better way is to display the total amount in a 'div' tag (for example) containing an attribute 'data-total' with the product's price.
Then, in JS, you can access to attribute's data and update the total with the price and the quantity.
Something like that:

```
<div class='total_amount' data-price='<?php echo $product['price']?>' >
  0
</div>
```

And then update your JS file as:

```
$(".ddd").on("click", function () {
    var $button = $(this),
        $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input");
    var oldValue = $input.val(),
        newVal;
    if ($.trim($button.text()) == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 1) {
            newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 1;
        }
    }
    $input.val(newVal);
    var price = $('.total_amount').data('price');
    $('.total_amount').html(price * newVal);
});
```

Hope it will help you :)

PS: Sorry for my English, I'm French :P

Comment: Yes, @YaatSuka, Thanks for the reply. Give me some to check your code.

Comment: Not sure if '.html()' method is JQuery, I think it's Ajax. 
If it doesn't work, try 'innerHTML'

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I tried your code, I am getting the issue, if I refreshed the page then total amount is showing 0, and qty is showing proper which Is selected.

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't think about that! For that, you can add a hidden field with the total amount, and update it at the same time as the total displayed.

Comment: I don't see why it would be a bad way to do. Hidden fields are generally used to get some data in the view file.

Comment: I am trying first time shopping cart., Actually, Qty ts showing perfectly if I refresh the page because qty is in session but amount is showing 0

Comment: You can check my add to cart code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369021/after-refreshing-the-page-product-adding-automatically-in-cart/46394765?noredirect=1#comment79754738_46394765

Comment: Try to put in your JS file:
$(document).ready(function() {  $('div.total_amount').val($('input.hidden').val()); 
...} => Set the total value displayed with the value of the hidden field at the loading of the page ;)

Comment: Sorry, the good syntaxe is: $('div.total_amount').innerHTML =
 ($('input.hidden').val();

Comment: Please check it, Assist me, What I am doing wrong here

Comment: Ok I'm looking at your code, let me a minute. 
Meanwhile, open the console (when you inspect elements), click on plus or minus button and tell me if an error is displayed on the console.

Comment: When clicked on Plus then I got Used of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.in jquery.js file

Comment: What actually I am doing is, I am creating a shopping cart, If any user clicked on Add to cart button then That product will add in the session(session Link I shared with you). then if any user trying to increase the qty of the product then total amount will be displayed.(I share the my-cart code in above link)